# Calling a variadic function template through a std::function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template function declared as follows:

```
template <typename ...Arguments>
double pricer(Arguments... params);
```

With specializations for different argument types.

What's the correct syntax for calling the template specializations through a single `std::function` "wrapper"? Is it possible?

Comment: It's not possible.  A single `std::function` will hold only a single specialization.  Though you could create a functor wrapping all of those different specializations.  That might help solve whatever it is you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot bind a template function with to `std::function`, only a particular instantiation of a template function can be stored there.